# FullCalendar not loading events from json after first load except in IE

Tags: events, rendering, fullcalendar

I have been testing out some code and I need to load day view with my own json data.

```
$('#day-calendar').fullCalendar('removeEvents');
// logic goes here to create dayViewEvents
$('#day-calendar').fullCalendar('addEventSource', eval(dayViewEvents));
```

This code gets called several times. The events render perfectly in IE, but in Chrome, FireFox and Safari the items do not show except for on the initial load.

Here is a sample of the json

```
[{"id":"T111","title":"OLIVER DOUGLAS","allDay":false,"start":"2010-12-27T08:00:00","end":"2010-12-27T08:00:00","url":null,"className":"myClass","editable":false,"source":null,"description":null,"eventType":"A Task"},
{"id":"T345","title":"EB DAWSON","allDay":false,"start":"2010-12-27T09:00:00","end":"2010-12-27T10:00:00","url":null,"className":"myRedClass","editable":false,"source":null,"description":null,"eventType":"A Call"}]
```

I tried rerender, refetch but nothing works. In IE it works every time with the above code.

One other thing - I called 'clientEvents' and they are in the calendar.

Thanks, 
Paul

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I probably should have done this as a comment but I wanted to make it readable.

The calendar is working fine, it was my goof in the javascript. I had :

```
$('#day-calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', dt.getYear(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
```

instead of :

```
$('#day-calendar').fullCalendar('gotoDate', **dt.getFullYear**(), dt.getMonth(), dt.getDate());
```

Apparently IE returns **2010** from getYear and all other browsers return **110**. The key is to allways **use getFullYear** and **not getYear**, which is deprecated. Oh well.